# Where to safely park a car in Hamburg for few days?

Tags: budget, germany, automobiles, security, hamburg

I am driving to Hamburg in few days and will stay there three days.

Is there s any public, safe parking not far from the city centre? Otherwise, is there any private parking having good prices for long term stays?

I read in [Parking Hamburg](http://www.car-parking.eu/germany/hamburg):

> Cheap parking is possible on walking distance from the centre, behind
>   the Central Train Station : € 5.00/day.

but I wonder how safe it is to leave the car there.

Comment: I find Hamburg really easy to find parking. Where will you be staying in Hamburg? I used to park my car outside my house and it's free.

Comment: @toy around St Pauli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Parkopedia has plenty of parking spots marked out around St. Pauli.](http://www.parkopedia.de/parking/st_pauli_hamburg_germany/?ac=1&country=DE&lat=53.5523495&lng=9.96649160000004) With costs ranging from 0 to 37 EUR per 24h. Some are hotel parking spots, with reduced rates for their guests, who nevertheless allow other to park too.

[image: Parkopedia marks plenty of parking spots around St. Pauli, Hamburg, with costs ranging from 0 to 37 EUR per 24h.]

Arguably the highest level of safety will be provided by an underground / locked parking with CCTV, as opposed to a public street parking. However those parkings are unlikely to be cheap. Up to you to pick a place.

Comment: Parking outside in St. Pauli during New Year's Eve is not the smartest idea. But the question sounded like it was intended for January, so that should be fine enough. Just stay away from Reeperbahn with the car and don't leave valuables in it.

Comment: Thanks! This worked very well. There was free parking during the weekend (almost on Sunday, until Monday 8 am) and then parking for 10€/day was easy to find.